# Configure nginx proxypass with node.js

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js

What I'm trying to do is running a node.js app with nginx using the ProxyPass feature; my node.js app is execute at localhost:8888, and the this is my nginx configuration file

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    server_name mywebsiteexample.com:80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
    }

}
```

And then when I go to my page (www.mywebsiteexample.com); the server response well but the related files are not found (css, images, etc).